# Renderred image looks like a mess

Tags: rendering

This is my render viewport image:

[image: render view]

And this is what it looks like when i do the render:
[image: renderred image]

What have I done wrong? How can i get renderred image to look like in render view?

Comment: Make Sure the forward part of TEXT dom zdravla is extruded and  [obviously] forward of the background .. probably the Y axis.  Please view meshes from top. Do not place at same Y axis location.   Note how temereen is forward of the background in the Y direction and extruded, we can see a forward shadow. Search z-fighting.

Comment: Found out what was the problem, Couple objects i used to cut out other objects with, were renderred. I clicked to hide them, but they were still renderred. I moved them to last layer and now it renders just fine. But thanks anyway :)